# Why can't I set a class in Domain Layer as abstract class with Clean Architecture?

Tags: kotlin, clean-architecture

I'm learning Clean Architecture with the [artical](https://proandroiddev.com/clean-architecture-data-flow-dependency-rule-615ffdd79e29).

I know Domain Layer is the most INNER part of the onion (no dependencies with other layers) and it contains Entities, Use cases & Repository Interfaces.

I think I should use abstract class or interface in Use Case in Domain Layout, you can see Image 1 in the artical above.

**Image 1**
[image]

The following code is from the project https://github.com/igorwojda/android-showcase

The `internal class GetAlbumListUseCase` is in Domain Layer, you can see Image 2.

I think `GetAlbumListUseCase` should be abstract class.

But I get *"Cannot create an instance of an abstract class"* error when I replace it with `internal abstract class GetAlbumListUseCase(...)`.

1: What wrong with me? Does it cause by AlbumDomainModule.kt during Kodein ?

2: Should I use abstract class or interface in Use Case in Domain Layout?

**GetAlbumListUseCase.kt**

```
internal class GetAlbumListUseCase(
    private val albumRepository: AlbumRepository
) {

    sealed class Result {
        data class Success(val data: List<Album>) : Result()
        data class Error(val e: Throwable) : Result()
    }

    suspend fun execute(): Result {
        // Due to API limitations search with custom phrase have to be performed to get albums
        val phrase = "Jackson"

        return try {
            Result.Success(albumRepository.searchAlbum(phrase).filter { it.getDefaultImageUrl() != null })
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Result.Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

**AlbumDomainModule.kt**

```
internal val domainModule = Kodein.Module("${MODULE_NAME}DomainModule") {

    bind() from singleton { GetAlbumListUseCase(instance()) }

    bind() from singleton { GetAlbumUseCase(instance()) }
}
```

**Image 2**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate an abstract class, because it is... well, abstract.

You misunderstood what it means that we should use abstractions. Your components should **depend** on abstractions (preferably interfaces, not abstract classes), but you still need to provide implementations (normal, not abstract classes). To do this, split your existing class into interface + its implementation, use implementation when configuring DI and use interface everywhere else.

For example, rename your `GetAlbumListUseCase` into `GetAlbumListUseCaseImpl`, create an interface `GetAlbumListUseCase` with its API (in IntelliJ you can use refactor -> extract interface) and make `GetAlbumListUseCaseImpl` implement `GetAlbumListUseCase`. Then use `GetAlbumListUseCase` everywhere in your code, but configure DI with `GetAlbumListUseCaseImpl`. This is exactly as with `PostRepository` and `PostRepositoryImpl` in the article linked by you.

With such architecture you could create alternative implementations of `GetAlbumListUseCase` in the future and switch them smoothly. You could even use multiple implementations at the same time, for example different objects use different implementations `GetAlbumListUseCase`. Note that in your current architecture all objects directly depend on a specific implementation, so switching to another one requires to modify half of your code.

Comment: Thanks! The project https://github.com/igorwojda/android-showcase isn't strict Clean Architecture, right?

If the project implement Clean Architecture strictly, it should be create an interface GetAlbumListUseCase with its API in Domain Layout and create GetAlbumListUseCaseImpl implement GetAlbumListUseCase in Data Layout, right?

Comment: I don't really know this "Clean Architecture" thing. These guidelines are just an universal set of rules or good practices when designing a software architecture, no matter how you call it. My opinion is that preemptively creating a separate interface and implementation for each and every class is too verbose, it's overengineering. But I do encourage to use abstractions pretty often. Common sense applies.