# Why does the author need to set dependency injection in Domain Layer with Clean Architecture?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, clean-architecture

I'm learning Clean Architecture with the [artical](https://proandroiddev.com/clean-architecture-data-flow-dependency-rule-615ffdd79e29) .

I know Domain Layer is the most INNER part of the onion (no dependencies with other layers) and it contains Entities, Use cases & Repository Interfaces.

The following code is from the project https://github.com/lopspower/CleanRxArchitecture

GetListRepo.kt and RepoRepository.kt are located in Domain Layer, you can see Image 1

1: I think the `GetListRepo` class should be abstract or interface, right?

2: There are three parameters for constructor of the class `GetListRepo`. I don't understand why the author add dependency injection `@Inject` for the class's constructor.
I think I can instance `GetListRepo` with any way in Data Layout, why does the author need to set dependency injection in Domain Layer with Clean Architecture ?

**GetListRepo.kt**

```
class GetListRepo
@Inject internal constructor(
    private val repoRepository: RepoRepository,
    useCaseScheduler: UseCaseScheduler? = null, 
    logger: Logger? = null
) : SingleUseCase<List<Repo>, String>(useCaseScheduler, logger) {
   ...

}
```

**RepoRepository.kt**

```
interface RepoRepository {
   val isConnected: Boolean
   ...
}
```

**Image 1**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to your [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68250425/why-cant-i-set-a-class-in-domain-layer-as-abstract-class-with-clean-architectur/68339639#68339639) about interfaces/abstract classes. I will quote myself:

> With such architecture you could create alternative implementations of GetAlbumListUseCase in the future and switch them smoothly. You could even use multiple implementations at the same time, for example different objects use different implementations GetAlbumListUseCase. Note that in your current architecture all objects directly depend on a specific implementation, so switching to another one requires to modify half of your code.

Imagine you did as you suggested, you didn't use dependency injection, but you created `GetListRepo` object everywhere in your code. Then in the future you need to have two alternative ways of providing the data, e.g. with local files and with remote server. Imagine you need to make it configurable in the application settings. Or imagine that you need to create unit tests and it would be good to provide a fake, testing variant of the `GetListRepo`.

How would you do this if your code everywhere would just instantiate `GetListRepo` directly? You would need to modify many different places in the code and put some logic related to loading of application settings, etc. everywhere. By using dependency injection all components receive their dependencies from outside, they don't know how they're being created and you can put your creation logic in one place only.

Making long story short: using DI lets us decouple components of our application. It makes our code more flexible and adaptable to different scenarios.

Comment: Thanks! Domain Layer is the most INNER part of the onion by the Clean Architecture artical, it's independent, I think Domain Layer can't couple with DI, right?